# How to make a lockscreen and enter password to unlock with pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a lock screen, when I click on a button, an input require password show up. I set a password, when type a valid password and press enter, the lockscreen disappear. Thank you guys!

Here is my demo : https://jsbin.com/rugoqupora/edit?html,css,js,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<button>Lockscreen</button>
 <div class="lock-screen">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Password">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
.lock-screen {
  display: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: none;
}
```

```
btn = document.querySelector('button');
lockscreen = document.querySelector('.lock-screen');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  lockscreen.style.display = 'flex';
})
```

Comment: please share the code you have tried to achieve this. SO is not a coding service, thanks!

Comment: Note that you can't make a real lock screen for the device, a sandboxed browser tab doesn't have the rights needed.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can easily create the form input etc. But you'll have to host your server to store all the credentials, and send the credentials (hashed) to the sever.

When you want to check if it's valid, just hash the password you typed in, and send it to the server, then if the server says it matches the one stored, then let them through.

I've created an example login dialog here.

```js
function showLogin() {
  // .show() doesn't work with transitions
  $("#u, #p").val("");
  $("#login").show().css("opacity", "1");
  $("#loginBackground").show().css("opacity", "0.5");
}

function hideLogin() {
  // .hide() doesn't work with transitions,
  // but you need it for user interaction
  // with objects behind it.
  $("#login, #loginBackground").css("opacity", "0").hide();
}

function login() {
  var username = $("#u").val();
  var password = $("#p").val();
  // Do something here!
}
```

```css
input {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: white;
  border: solid 1px black;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  width: 200px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.big-button {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.login {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  width: 188px;
}

input[type="button"],
input[type="submit"],
button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#login {
  transition: 0.2s;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  top: 8px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: -150px;
  height: 150px;
  z-index: 10000;
}

#loginBackground {
  transition: 0.2s;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.small-button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.no-border {
  border: none;
}

.close {
  color: red;
  left: 30px;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.accept {
  color: lime;
  right: 30px;
  top: 25px;
}

.login-button {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 26px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.login-button:hover,
.login-button:focus,
.login-button:active {
  background: rgb(127, 127, 255);
  color: white;
}

.shadow {
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

* {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
span,
div,
body {
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.login-title {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center">
  <h1>Foo Bar</h1>
  <input class="shadow no-border big-button" type="button" value="Login" onclick="showLogin();">
</div>
<div id="loginBackground" style="opacity: 0; display: none;"></div>
<div id="login" style="opacity: 0; display: none;" class="shadow" action="https://example.com">
  <h3 class="login-title">Login to Foo Bar</h3>
  <input placeholder="Username or Email" id="u" class="login shadow no-border" type="textbox"><br/>
  <input placeholder="Password" id="p" class="login shadow no-border" type="password"><br/>
  <input class="shadow no-border small-button accept login-button" type="button" onclick="hideLogin(); login(); " value="&#10003;"><br/>
  <input class="shadow no-border small-button close login-button" type="button" onclick="hideLogin(); " value="&cross;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no possible way to make a lock screen using pure JavaScript!  You can make an artificial one that stores the credentials within itself, but hackers could easily just look in the code and get the username/password, therefor making it unsafe.

The only way to truly achieve this is using a server-side language (Like PHP, Node.js) alongside a web language (Like JavaScript). Although, to do this you would need to set up a server (or multiple) that store the credentials, and then send the user's input to the server and have the *server* check to make sure they are correct. That way the client never stores the password, making it impossible for others to find. (As long as you protect your server well enough and code it right.)

Comment: Please stop adding  noise to your post and read about [**How to Answer questions here**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Greetings and statements like “I hope that helps” are seen as noise here because they don’t actually form part of the answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanna the lockscreen disapear when I type the password that created before. I dont want to make that complicated like using server, things like that. Password is just declared in a variable.